# Accessing Key Vault Key Identifier

Tags: azure, terraform

I have created a key vault and a key using Terraform that will be used to encrypt a VM using Azure Disk Encryption.

The extension that is installed on the VM to encrypt the disk wants the following **"KeyEncryptionKeyURL"**. This URL can be found when you go into the key vault, select the key and look at the setting called key identifier.

Using **azurerm_key_vault_key** there are no options to output the URL. Instead, I've tried to build the URL by combining other bits together but I just cannot get it working.

Please may someone help me with this?

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ext_ade" {
    depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.ext_domain_join, azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.ext_dsc]
    count = var.session_hosts.quantity
    name =  var.ext_ade.name
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.*.id[count.index]
    publisher = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
    type = "AzureDiskEncryption"
    type_handler_version = "2.2"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

    settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
        "KeyVaultURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri}keys/${azurerm_key_vault_key.ade_key[count.index].name}/${azurerm_key_vault_key.ade_key[count.index].version}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
        "VolumeType": "All"
    }
    SETTINGS

    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [settings]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done this and have the code. I had to build it through the format string. If you nudge me on Monday I’ll drop you what I have.

Comment: @Jason, thank you, hopefully you can provide what you did as I'm currently unable to find what I need to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
I have managed to resolve my own issue, basically it was a typo in my code. One of the inputs I set was **KeyVaultResourceID**, when it should have been **KekVaultResourceID**, once this was changed it encrypted my virtual machines.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ext_ade" {
    depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.ext_domain_join, 
   azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.ext_dsc]
   count = var.session_hosts.quantity
    name = var.ext_ade.name  
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.*.id[count.index]
    publisher = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
    type = "AzureDiskEncryption"
    type_handler_version = "2.2"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

    settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
        "KeyVaultURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.vault_uri}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "${azurerm_key_vault_key.ade_key.*.id[count.index]}",
        "KekVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
        "VolumeType": "All"
    }
    SETTINGS

    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [settings]
    }
}
```